# Loop through all tables and detect changed rows using checksum or hashbytes

Tags: sql-server, audit

All the tables have an extra row called checksum which is stored by doing `INSERT INTO example_table VALUES ('a','b', BINARY_CHECKSUM('a','b'))`.

Suppose someone change a row value, obviously the checksum will change, and when I run `Select CHECKSUM_AGG(*) FROM example_table`, that value will differ from the stored checksum.
How can I detect, looping through all tables, what row or table was changed?
Can I do this with a Stored Procedure? This is an SQL SERVER database.

Comment: Audit all tables and detect data changes. That's sort of the point of the question.

Comment: There's a [built-in functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) for auditing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
where BINARY_CHECKSUM('a','b') <> checksumCol
```

But if they can change a or b they can change the checksumCol

Comment: I know it´s not a very good idea to store the checksum, but how can I determine that the new value differs from the actual value?

Comment: Use timestamp or just don't give them update authority